# How can I implement an absolute value operation?

Tags: c, math, mathematical-expressions, absolute-value

How can I print the absolute value of a result?

Example:

- `|4-5|` the result will be 1 (negative sign will be neglected)
- `|5-4|` this also have the answer of 1 (positive value remains as positive value)

Comment: Try `unsigned max = a > b ? ((unsigned) a - (unsigned) b) : ((unsigned) b - (unsigned) a);`.  This avoids overflow trouble with `abs(a-b)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking for the `abs()` function from `<stdlib.h>`, which accepts an `int` and returns the absolute value (converting negative numbers to positive):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%i\n", abs(4-5));
  printf("%i\n", abs(5-4));
}
```

There is also `fabs()` which does the same for `double` values if you are working with floating point, and several other variants for wider data types.

You can of course alternatively implement a function like `abs()` yourself. A simple example (not intended to be optimal):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int my_abs(int v) {
  if (v >= 0) return v;
  else        return -v;
}

int main() {
  printf("%i\n", my_abs(4-5));
  printf("%i\n", my_abs(5-4));
}
```

Comment: Can you do it without using the library function?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the `4,5` are .... are they floats or integers or something else? What encoding?

For an integer with [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) you can:

```
#define abs(x) ((x<0)?(-x):x)
```

For data types with a sign bit instead it’s enough to clear the sign bit, so for example for a 32-bit integer in such encoding you can:

```
#define abs(x) (x&0x7FFFFFFF)
```

which is branchless. However, it is usual the `int` type is in two's complement in most environments, so you can not use this on them. However, floating point types are stored like this all the time, so they can be `abs` ed like this easily... just use pointers or union to get access to bit operations on them

```
float abs(float x)
{
    union
    {
        float f32;
        int i32;
    } u;

    u.f32 = x;
    u.i32 &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
    return u.f32;
}
```

Comment: The macro shown above evaluates its argument multiple times, which can lead to subtle bugs if the passed argument expression includes side effects. It's safer and more robust to use a real function for that purpose.

Comment: All modern processors you're likely to encounter use 2s complement encoding for `int`, so the second macro will basically never correctly provide the requested behavior for ints.

Comment: @DanBonachea its highly unclear what the target datatype is ... it might be bigint, arbnum or whatever ... real function is a performance hit but yes if x is expression it could lead to problems however as implementation example its more than enough ...

Comment: @Spektre Can you come to the chat room please ?